# Why I can't work with potgreSQL testdatabase, however development postgreSQL is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm trying to start to working with PostgreSQL and have some troubles.

I create database for development and it is working. I've already created table and added some objects. I followed this post to create databases - http://blog.deliciousrobots.com/2011/12/13/get-postgres-working-on-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/

Here is the code, what I run to create test_database

```
denmed@denmed:~/projects/internet_shop$ sudo -u postgres createdb -O denys    internet_shop_test
denmed@denmed:~/projects/internet_shop$ psql -d internet_shop_test -U denys -WPassword for user denys: 
denmed@denmed:~/projects/internet_shop$ psql -d internet_shop_test -U denys -W
 Password for user denys: 
 psql (9.1.7)
 Type "help" for help.
 internet_shop_test=>
```

This means I create database and can work with it or NOT ?

Then, it other console(when I was logged in test database in another console) I run command

```
 rake test
```

and get this errors( I will cut it ):

```
   Errors running test:units! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:      
database "internet_shop_test" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
 : DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "internet_shop_test">
 Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby 
-I"lib:test" -I"/home/denmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib" "/home    
/denmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" 
"test/functional/**/*_test.rb" ]>
```

Ok, it tells me that I'm accessing the database. Then I closed logged in test db terminal and run rake test again and get this:

```
  PG::Error: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
  ...
 Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", 
"database"=>"internet_shop_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"denys", 
"password"=>"********"}
 ...
PG::Error: FATAL:  database "internet_shop_test" does not exist
```

Here is my database.yml for development and test databases:

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: internet_shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: denys 
  password: ********

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: internet_shop_test
  pool: 5
  username: denys 
  password: ********
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User "denys" does not have permission to create databases. The error is pretty clear,

I don't know if you can tell rails to create the database using a different (superuser) account, or just skip the create database step.

Oh - you don't need the "-W" flag on psql either, it'll ask you for a password if it wants one.

Comment: It is just strange, because I created development database using the same commands as I'm using here.So you think I need to create superuser ?

Comment: No you didn't. You created the database as user postgres. Then you connected to the database as "denys".